# Writing data to plist for tablelview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got the following plist:

[image]

This plist stores an array which will be loaded in a UITableview as you can see on the right.

I retrieve this content with the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"array" ofType:@"plist"];
vakken = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

naamvakken = [vakken objectForKey:@"Vakken"];

self.array = [naamvakken mutableCopy];
```

Now I use this UIAlertview with this Textfield build-in feature to let the user make a new row:

http://f.cl.ly/items/030Z373X2p1c3m0O0u2K/Schermafbeelding%202013-01-21%20om%2019.48.06.png
With this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"array" ofType:@"plist"];

NSString *list = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];

naamvakken = [vakken objectForKey:@"Vakken"];

[array addObject:list];

[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

But for one reason or another, above code stores the text in the TableView but NOT in the plist. Is there something wrong with my code? `[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];` should do the trick?

Another question is how to remove a string from the plist if the user swipes to right on the tableviewcell.

My .h

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIView *root;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *vakken;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *naamvakken;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPathToBeDeleted;

@end
```

for: H2CO3:

```
-(NSString *)docsDir {

    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

and in the viewdidload:

```
listPath = [[self docsDir]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.plist"];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each day a question about this very same problem arises on StackOverflow. The problem is here:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"array" ofType:@"plist"];
```

You can't write to the application bundle (for quite obvious security reasons). If you want to update the plist, write it to a writable path, such as the Documents directory.

Comment: @user1883396 Docs please. You'll need to use the NSSearchPathsForDirectoriesInDomains function.

Comment: Im ask this question because I can't find it on the internet or on the apple docs.. I just need a solutions for this problem dealing with it for 4 hours now...

Comment: @user1883396 I see. As I mentioned, please try using the "NSSearchPathsForDirectoriesInDomains()" function.

Comment: Try using it where and how? I found this: -(NSString *)docsDir {
    
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    
}

Comment: @user1883396 Substitute the path to the propertly list with the return value of this method when you're intending to write it.

Comment: Something like the changed code above? and than listPath would be my path which I can use in [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; to [array writeToFile:listPath atomically:YES];

Comment: Well that didn't worked. When I make the new object for the array it will display the new row. When I restart the app the array change to empty?

Comment: @user1883396 it should work for sure. Check if the plist is written. Sorry, I have to go now.